How to resolve "Namespace '"playcanvas"' has no exported member 'Entity'" when using PlayCanvas CDN in Vite + React + TypeScript?
When importing PlayCanvas using the CDN, I'm encountering the following TypeScript error:
Namespace '"playcanvas"' has no exported member 'Entity'.

My Setup:

Node: v20.9.0
Yarn: v1.22.0
TypeScript: v5.5.4
Vite: v5.4.3
PlayCanvas CDN: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/playcanvas

I added the PlayCanvas CDN in index.html using an import map:
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "playcanvas": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/playcanvas"
    }
  }
</script>

Then I installed PlayCanvas locally for TypeScript support:
yarn add -D playcanvas

In my component, I import PlayCanvas like this:
import * as pc from "playcanvas";

this is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node",
      "@testing-library/react",
      "@testing-library/jest-dom",
      "react",
      "react-dom",
      "vite/client"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
      "@widgets/*": ["src/widgets/*"],
      "@features/*": ["src/features/*"],
      "@entities/*": ["src/entities/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["src/shared/*"]
    },
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "./jest.setup.ts", "src/playcanvas.d.ts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}


What did you try and what were you expecting?
I followed the TypeScript instructions from the official PlayCanvas documentation here. Initially, I set up the import map like this in my index.html:
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "playcanvas": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/playcanvas"
    }
  }
</script>

I expected this setup to allow me to import PlayCanvas directly from the CDN and use its classes and methods within my React components.
In my component files, I imported PlayCanvas like this:
import * as pc from 'playcanvas';

However, the TypeScript compilation failed, and I got errors like:
Namespace '"playcanvas"' has no exported member 'Entity'.

To resolve this, I added a playcanvas.d.ts declaration file with the following content to declare the module and expose it from the CDN:
declare module "playcanvas" {
  export * from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/playcanvas";
}

Next, I tried adding the vite-plugin-cdn-import in my vite.config.ts as follows:
import cdnImport from "vite-plugin-cdn-import";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    cdnImport({
      modules: [
        {
          name: "playcanvas",
          var: "pc", // The global variable used by PlayCanvas
          path: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/playcanvas", // CDN path for PlayCanvas without the .js extension
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
});

With this, I expected PlayCanvas to be available from the CDN without being bundled or imported from node_modules.
What happened instead?
When I used the CDN, I kept getting the same TypeScript errors:
src/pages/GameBoard/api/ICard.ts:5:35 - error TS2694: Namespace '"playcanvas"' has no exported member 'Entity'.

5 export interface ICard extends pc.Entity;

and:
src/pages/GameBoard/api/IPlayAnimationMoveTo.ts:5:19 - error TS2694: Namespace '"playcanvas"' has no exported member 'Vec3'.

5   initialPos?: pc.Vec3; // initial position (optional)

It seems like PlayCanvas is not properly recognized by TypeScript when using the CDN. But If I remove the CDN and install it then it works. I also already try it removing the installed playcanvas version and  deleteing yarn.lock, cleaning yarn cache, deleting node_modules
